# AnyCancellable.store(in:) with Combine

Tags: swift, combine

Let’s say you are using the built-in `.store(in:)` method on AnyCancellable like so:

```
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let newPhotos = photos.selectedPhotos
newPhotos
  .map { [unowned self] newImage in
    return self.images.value + [newImage]
  }
  .assign(to: \.value, on: images)
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

If you have an app that does this a lot - are these removed when the publishers complete?

Also, If i decide to go with this approach instead:

```
private var newPhotosSubscription: AnyCancellable?

self.newPhotosSubscription = newPhotos
  .map { [unowned self] newImage in
    self.images.value + [newImage]
  }
  .assign(to: \.value, on: images)
```

Everytime I call the method again, it override the AnyCancellable, what happens to the previous one? Does it still complete before being deallocated?

Comment: Usually you need the `cancelable` to listen to something the view needs updates from. By default as long as the view lives, the `cancelable` (and therefore the subscription) lives. You may set the your `AnyCancelable` to nil (or a new one) to destroy/replace the current subscription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dávid Pásztor's solution is close, but it has a race condition. Specifically, suppose the `newPhotos` publisher completes synchronously, *before* the `sink` method returns. Some publishers operate this way. `Just` and `Result.Publisher` both do, among others.

In that case, the completion block runs before `sink` returns. Then, `sink` returns an `AnyCancellable` which is stored in `newPhotosSubscription`. But the subscription has already completed, so `newPhotosSubscription` will never be set back to nil.

So for example if you use a `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` in live code but substitute a `Just` publisher in some test cases, the tests could trigger the race condition.

Here's one way to fix this: keep track of whether the subscription has completed. Check it after `sink` returns, before setting `newPhotosSubscription`.

```
private var ticket: AnyCancellable? = nil

if ticket == nil {
    var didComplete = false
    let newTicket = newPhotos
        .sink(
            receiveValue: { [weak self] in
                self?.images.value.append($0)
            },
            receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
                didComplete = true
                self?.ticket = nil
            }
        )
    if !didComplete {
        ticket = newTicket
    }
}
```

> Everytime I call the method again, it override the AnyCancellable, what happens to the previous one? Does it still complete before being deallocated?

The previous one, if any, is cancelled, because the only reference to the old `AnyCancellable` is destroyed and so the `AnyCancellable` is destroyed. When an `AnyCancellable` is destroyed, it cancels itself (if not already cancelled).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out! +++

Comment: @rob mayoff, thanks. May I know what is the difference if I use ticket.cancel() instead of doing the ticket == nil check in the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

A `Set<T>` doesn't know anything about `T`, and certainly doesn't know that it is a Combine `AnyCancellable`.  The documentation for `store(in:)` does not say that it will monitor the subscription and remove it.

So, nothing automatic is going to happen when it completes, but you could remove it from the `Set` yourself.

If you let a `AnyCancellable` get dealloced (there is no GC in Swift) by dropping all references to it, you have cancelled the subscription.  It will not wait around for a completion.

It is possible for a specific type of cancellable (for example, one you make) to decide that it always completes and to do so right before deallocation.

Comment: I see.. but what would be your approach then? let's say I want to start a new one only once the previous one is finished, I also don't want to stack them waiting in a list if there is one that hasnt completed yet, because they do the same job...

Comment: @Jaythaking you won't be able to handle that with `Cancellable`s, you need to handle that on the `Publisher` side, before creating the subscription. Also, you need to clarify what behaviour you are expecting: if you already have a running task, do you want to add the new one to a queue? Or do you only want to start a new task if the previous one already finished?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I would like to start a new task only if the previous one has already finished..

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal of only creating a new subscription if the previous one has already finished, while also making sure that the previous subscription is thrown away as soon as it is finished, you're best off storing a reference to your `AnyCancellable` directly, not in a `Set`.

You should check if you already have a subscription and only start one if you don't, then instead of the `assign`, use a `sink` and in case you receive a completion, set the `AnyCancellable` reference to `nil`. This will ensure that once your current subscription finished, you can start a new one.

```
private var newPhotosSubscription: AnyCancellable?

if newPhotosSubscription == nil {
    newPhotosSubscription = newPhotos
        .map { [unowned self] newImage in
            self.images.value + [newImage]
        }
        .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
            self.images.value = value
        }, receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
            newPhotosSubscription = nil
        })
    }
}
```